Sliding delay and timer solution with durable storage in AWS
I have a requirement to create a sliding timers

When event-type-A with ID happens, create a record with ID and timer of 60 minutes
When event-type-B happens with ID, update the record of ID to reset the timer of 60 minutes
When record expires, emit to SQS queue

I need to be able to

From an input with an UUID, create a timer of 60 minutes
From an input with an already received UUID, update the timer of 60 minutes
Able to replay bring down and bring back up compute infrastructure without losing timers
Timers actioned as quick to zero as possible

My problem is how to do this reliably. App servers may or may not be available at a given time to action on a zeroed timer but need to be able to action when they comes back online. All timers (or information on the time) must be stored outside the app server. There could be up to 10k timers at a given time.
I could solve this with Redis/Elasticache TTLs

App Servers would react to event-type-A and create/update the record in-memory with 60 minutes
App Servers would subscribe to the keyevent expiries and emit to the SQS queue when they expiry

However the data isn't robustly stored so updates to the underlying Elasticache loses all records, or availability of the app servers can result in the missed timers. Also the redis server doesn't reliably emit the event after 60 minutes exactly; it can be delayed based on the amount of items on the cache the redis server is dealing with.
Was looking at couple of options to reliably store and react to timers in a table, but getting stalled

DynamoDB TTLs can last days and are less reliable than redis TTLs
DynamoDB and a cronjob lambda (every minute) as a replacement, but the main problem is the lambda would need to scan the table to get all the records and determine if the expiry time took place (lastUpdatedTime > 60 mins). Can't use query as the ID may contain multiple timers and the PK/SK can't change values (without having to delete the old key and add the new key)
SQS has max delay time of 15 mins


If you go down the Redis route you can use MemoryDB which is Redis with a durable datastore.
DynamoDB TTL will not give you the granularity you need.
EventBridge Schedules would probably be a good way to implement it, you could use DynamoDB as the front end datastore and use streams and Lambda to update the schedules should event B happen.
With EventBridge schedules you get 1 min granularity of events. You can have the event push into an SQS queue that your application can pull from. When your application comes back up you'll have all the missed events in the queue.
The only thing to be careful of is if an event zerod out and went into the queue, then event B also tried to update it while your application was down, you could get the event twice.
